# Material-ui drawer width issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, react-component

I'm facing an issue with material-ui drawer. I've changed the width of the drawer container which causes a a problem . The drawer remains a little inside the page and visible but I don't want to make it visible on the page while I haven't clicked the button. It might be having an issue with the transform attribute now.

So I changed it to **transform: translate(350px, 0px)** but then I'm getting another issue, that is if I am clicking the button the drawer is not showing up. **Any help on this thing ??**

**I have got the solution and edited the code.**

I've created a Demo here => [**Have a look**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vrcysu)

Also shared the code below:

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      openDrawer: false
    };
  }

  toggleDrawer() {
    this.setState({
      openDrawer: !this.state.openDrawer
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}> Toggle Drawer</button>
        <Drawer 
                  open={this.state.openDrawer}
                  containerClassName={!this.state.openDrawer? "hide-drawer": "show-drawer" }
                  openSecondary={true}
                  docked={true} 
                >
                    <div className="drawer-title-div">
                        <h4 className="drawer-title-text">It's my drawer</h4>
                    </div>
                </Drawer>
      </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**style.css**

```
h1, p {


font-family: Lato;
}

.show-drawer {
  top: 47px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  width: 80% !important;
  transform: translate(0%, 0px) !important;
}

.hide-drawer {
  top: 47px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  width: 80% !important;
  transform: translate(100%, 0px) !important;
}

/* .drawer-side-drawer:focus {
  top: 47px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  width: 350px !important;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) !important;
} */

.drawer-title-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F2F8FB;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.drawer-title-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  color: #484848;
  font-family: Muli;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a toggle class and you can get rid of the transform.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      openDrawer: false
    };
  }

  toggleDrawer() {
    this.setState({
      openDrawer: !this.state.openDrawer
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}> Toggle Drawer</button>
        <Drawer containerClassName={!this.state.openDrawer ? "hide-drawer": "show-drawer"} 
                  open={this.state.openDrawer}
                  openSecondary={true}
                  docked={true} 
                >
                    <div className="drawer-title-div">
                        <h4 className="drawer-title-text">It's my drawer</h4>
                    </div>
                </Drawer>
      </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks @Parvinder. your code helped me. Just edit it a little. write **containerClassName** instead of **className** there in the drawer.

Answer (score 34):

For mui version 5, you have to use the PaperProps prop like so:

```
        <Drawer
          PaperProps={{
            sx: { width: "90%" },
          }}
        >{...Child elements here}</Drawer>
```

Answer (score 6):

you can simply add this to index.css

```
.MuiDrawer-paper {
width: 60% !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .MuiDrawer-paper {
 width: 100% !important;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `PaperProps={{ style: { width: '25%' } }}` to your MUI Drawer.

Most Probably it will work for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this issue is by getting the parent width:

```js
const parentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

 <Box
  ref={parentRef}
 >
  <Drawer
    PaperProps={{
      sx: {
        width: parentRef?.current?.clientWidth || 0,
      },
    }}
  >
    // content goes here
  </Drawer>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.innerWidth` as `width: 100%`:

```
    <Drawer ...>
        <div style={{width: window.innerWidth * 0.25}}>
            ...
        </div>
    </Drawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

you just have to add the **PaperProps** to your drawer

Answer (score -1):

[Drawer-Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer) If you look at the link.. you will find Drawer properties..

> width (union:  string  number) [default : null]   The width of the Drawer in pixels or
>   percentage in string format ex. 50% to fill half of the window or 100%
>   and so on. Defaults to using the values from theme.

so just update the tag with width and you are good to go,

```
<Drawer width="50%"></Drawer>
```

Check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uxcpxn?file=style.css)..

The drawer width is not matching the theme drawer width which was causing the problem.. not the transform CSS attribute.

**Just a different approach** ^^

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import Responsive from 'react-responsive-decorator'; // This decorator allows using the library as a decorator.

@Responsive
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      openDrawer: false,
      width:350
    };

  }
  // Update for kinda media query thing
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.media({ minWidth: 768 }, () => {
      this.setState({
        width: 350
      });
    });
  this.props.media({ maxWidth: 768 }, () => {
      this.setState({
        width: 150
      });
    });
  }
  toggleDrawer() {
    this.setState({
      openDrawer: !this.state.openDrawer
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}> Toggle Drawer</button>
        <Drawer width={this.state.width} //<- Update
                  open={this.state.openDrawer}
                  containerClassName="drawer-side-drawer"
                  openSecondary={true}
                  docked={true} 
                >
                    <div className="drawer-title-div">
                        <h4 className="drawer-title-text">It's my drawer</h4>
                    </div>
                </Drawer>
      </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I want to apply it in the external css.

Comment: as I am also needing a different width for the mobile view

Comment: just click on this link - **https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vrcysu**. I have used the percentage for width in the external css file **style.css** but it's not working

Comment: @Subhojit not in css file... index.js file check my index.js file please and comment out width in css file .. I marked '<- updates'

Comment: yeah but I told you I want to apply this on the external css file which is **style.css** instead of applying it as inline css.

Comment: @Subhojit its not inline css... its a property of the drawer o.O

Comment: But I wanted solution to apply it on the external css file.

Comment: See the solution above you. That guy had given some solution which is a different approach to apply the style in external css. That solution resolved my problem and is usable for applying the styles on mobile views too (in media queries). You'll understand.

Comment: ok @Subhojit whatever works for you... problem is resolved that matters ...